# ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make a code using PyQt5 that shows me an animation of compressing a sin or cos wave depending on whether I press the right button on the window or the left one. I have used a number of classes and functions in my code and have imported the necessary  modules from libraries - I can mention these in details in the comments if necessary to aid my query.

However, I get an error message which directs me to a new file which belongs to the matplotlib files. I get that error is due to an incompatibility of data type or array type perhaps but don't understand what it is exactly - and why does the casting rule 'safe' mean in this scenario?

```
  File "C:\Users\NEHA\New folder\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 356, in __init__
    if not np.isfinite(figsize).all():

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I am unsure as to how I can condense the whole code but I can share with you a github link to the code perhaps?

Comment: o, in SO the posts must be self-contained. If your code is too long then create a new project oriented to the functionality that generates the problem.